# react_on_rails install: yarn is required error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby, reactjs, yarnpkg

I am trying to setup react_on_rails for an existing rails 5.0 app as per the following instructions:
https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails

1. gem "react_on_rails", "8.0.0"
2. rails generate react_on_rails:install

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: yarn is required. Please install it before continuing. https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
```

now this is my yarn, npm and node path:

```
[user@server]$ which node
/usr/bin/node
[user@server]$ which npm
/usr/bin/npm
[user@server]$ which yarn
~/.yarn/bin/yarn
```

How do i ensure it's using the appropriate yarn and help install react_on_rails?

EDIT: This is my ~/.bashrc file:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"


export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.yarn/bin"
```

This is my /bin/yarn file under my app:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
VENDOR_PATH = File.expand_path('..', __dir__)
Dir.chdir(VENDOR_PATH) do
  begin
    exec "yarnpkg #{ARGV.join(" ")}"
  rescue Errno::ENOENT
    $stderr.puts "Yarn executable was not detected in the system."
    $stderr.puts "Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install"
    exit 1
  end
end
```

Comment: What operating system are you using and how did you install yarn?

Comment: can you run `yarn install`? What is the output?

Comment: Would be better if you install yarn with brew. But anyway, add following to your `.bashrc`: `export PATH="$PATH:'yarn global bin'"` as it is described in [docs](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install) to have access to Yarn’s executables globally and make sure you have reloaded your `~/.bashrc` file with `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Have you installed webpack gem?

Comment: Looks like un-setting my http_proxy did it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use just `yarn` instead of `yarnpkg`?

```
exec "yarn #{ARGV.join(" ")}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if one the following fixed it:

```
unset https_proxy
unset http_proxy

npm config set proxy http://user:****@ip
npm config set https-proxy http://user:***@ip
```

After that yarn worked.